# Integration of an inverse trigonometric function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to find the integral of the following function:
$$\int\arccos\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2}\,dx.$$
I've already tried using integration by parts but the result is not very friendly so i'm wondering if there's any less complex method.

Comment: What did you use for integration by parts?

Comment: The function above as f(x) and y=x as derivative.

Comment: What do you mean by $y=x$?  Do you mean $dv=dx$?

Comment: The variable change $t=\arccos\sqrt{...}$?

Comment: Integration by parts doesn't seem too bad.  Perhaps you missed a chain rule step.  Could you edit your question to include your work?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, so I can't post a full answer, but integration by parts lead to a polynomial over $(x+1)^{5/2}$.  Then, expand the numerator in powers of $x+1$ or use the substitution $u=x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts works very well here:
$$
x\arccos\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}+\int x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x+1}{x+2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+2)^2}\,dx.
$$
After simplification, the last integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{x}{2(x+2)\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx=\int\frac{x}{x+2}\,d\sqrt{x+1}=
\int\left(1-\frac{2}{(x+1)+1}\right)\,d\sqrt{x+1}.
$$
I leave it here for you to finish.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int\arccos\pars{\root{x + 1 \over x + 2}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ \root{\pars{x + 1}/\pars{x + 2}}}{=}
\int{2t\arccos\pars{t} \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int\arccos\pars{t}\,\dd\pars{1 \over 1 - t^{2}} =
{\arccos\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}} + \int{\dd t \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{3/2}} =
{\arccos\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}} + {t \over \root{1 - t^{2}}}
\end{align}

> Since
>   $\ds{1 - t^2 = {1 \over x+ 2}}$:

\begin{align}
&\int\arccos\pars{\root{x + 1 \over x + 2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{\pars{x + 2}\arccos\pars{\root{x + 1 \over x + 2}} +
\root{\pars{x + 1}\pars{x + 2}} + \pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}}
\end{align}